# Javascript + jQuery image paralax with translate3d is lagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css

I have created a little Script that determines the position of the cursor on an image and moves the picture a bit with it, I try to achieve this with translate3d() but its lagging a bit and only stops lagging when you stop moving your cursor.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c31k00ve/1/

Inspiration (WARNING: Sound): https://html.nkdev.info/godlike/gallery.html

JS:

```
(function($) {
var $gallery = $('.gallery');
var relX, relY, $e;
$gallery.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $e = e;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(test);
});

var test = function () {
    var $container = $('.container');
    var offset = $container.offset();
    relX = $e.pageX - offset.left - $container.width() / 2;
    relY = $e.pageY - offset.top - $container.height() / 2;
    $gallery.css({
        transform: "translate3d(" + (relX * 0.1) + "px, " + (relY * 0.1) + "px, 0) scale(1.3)"
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Development</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="gallery"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="xcoord">a</span>
    <span class="ycoord">a</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 200px;
}
.gallery {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/200/200);
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.gallery:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.xcoord, .ycoord {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine on my machine and can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. You could move var $container = $('.container'); and the width / height calculations out of the function for some minor performance benefits. There's a lot going on with the page with video and audio, so it could just be that your processor is struggling a little.

Comment: I don't have any problems with the page I showed works perfectly fine there, only my own script is lagging. And my computer is definitely strong enough (i7-6700k + GTX1080)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the transition property. I can see why you have it on there for the hover effect at the start, but perhaps that could be achieved a different way.

Updated fiddle with my suggestion 
https://jsfiddle.net/c31k00ve/4/

```
.gallery {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/g/200/200);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.gallery:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Still lagging... to test it: Move the mouse over the image very slowly, then stop, the image will jump after you stop for a bit

Comment: Oh, I see that you mean now. Sorry, I thought it was a performance thing. Is it not just that you have a transition on the element and on element:hover? So you are updating the transform property on mousemove, but there is a transition, so it is "slow"?

Comment: Can you edit your anwer to that? That actually worked... This was such a dumb error, for testing I just removed the transition from the hover, removing it from the .gallery was the way to go. I will accept it afterwards, thanks